# Lightswitch HTML Client Date Data Display. Locale Aware in I.E. Not Locale Aware in FireFox

Tags: html, firefox, lightswitch-2013

HTML Client with a row list containing date data.

I.E. is locale aware (en-NZ) and displays
say 6/10/2014. for 6th October.

Firefox displays 10/6/2014.

Is there perhaps some HTML that I need to add to default.htm to force Firefox to use our locale. (The app is unlikely to move regions).

thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a way around this? All dates behave correctly in the other browsers - but not Firefox

Comment: No. We live with it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - shame about it :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple fix if there aren't to many is this code:

```
contentItem.dataBind("value", function (value) {
    if (value) {
        $(element).text(value.format("dd-MM-yyyy"));
    }
});
```

add it to the post render of the date and it forces the browser to display it in the correct format..

Answer (score 0):

As I covered in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586138/lightswitch-dates-in-firefox-displayed-incorrectly/28945366#28945366), the FireFox settings which dictate the locale are available on the Firefox options\languages screen.

The following example shows the appropriate settings "English/New Zealand [en-nz]" selected for your locale and the resulting dd/mm/yyyy date formatting: -

[image]