# Lightswitch dates in Firefox displayed incorrectly

Tags: lightswitch-2013

Does anyone know why all dates display in the correct (UK based) dd/MM/yyyy format in Chrome and IE but in Firefox are set to MM/dd/yyyy format?

Is there a workaround other than converting every date display to a custom control and using moment.js to render the date into the required format?

PC is set to UK location in Control Panel.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having encountered the same issue, and following some rabbit hole exploration in the msls library, we determined that the solution is to ensure the setting selected on the Firefox options\languages screen is "English/United Kingdom [en-gb]" as shown in the following example: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks this fixed the problem - I wonder why IE and Chrome work fine though - are they picking up the localisation from the os but Firefox isn't I wonder?